# How can I make a signum-like plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a signum-like plot with matplotlib based on this:

The x axis would be an interval in seconds: 0-60 
The plot would be 1 if the x is between the starts and the stops.
Elsewhere it should be 0.

```
label   sec1       sec2

start   5.063      8.293
time    0.184      1.033
stop    5.247      9.326
```

So if X is

0 < X < 5.063 --> 0

5.063 =< X =< 5,247 --> 1

5.247 < X < 8.293 --> 0

8.293 =< X =< 9.326--> 1

9.326 < X < 60 --> 0

There would be more sections, not just two, and the line should be continous.

Maybe its an easy question, but I'm fairly new to python and matplotlib.
I tried to google it, but all the answers is about the sin plot instead of sign plot. I'm not even sure what to google to find correct answer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: matplotlib only plots points, so you have just to provide the correct y points to `plt.plot(x, y)`

Comment: Oh, I get it. I need some colection like a list for y points (which are 0 or 1)
But how can I make that list based on the little intervals?

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib plots points, not functions. You have to provide
the correct y points. You could do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


starts = np.arange(1, 55, 4)
stops = starts + 1

x = np.linspace(0, 60, 1000)
y = np.zeros_like(x)

for start, stop in zip(starts, stops):
    mask = np.logical_and(x > start, x <= stop)
    y[mask] = 1

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(0, 1.1)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: result]

## Edit: second solution with real rectangular pulses and less points

This is a better solution assuming the start and stops do not overlap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

starts = np.arange(1, 55, 4)
stops = starts + 1

x = np.repeat(np.sort(np.append(starts, stops)), 2)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
y[1::4] = 1
y[2::4] = 1

plt.plot(x, y)
```

For the x values we join starts and stops together with `np.append`, sort them to get them in chronological order with `np.sort` and repeat each value twice with `np.repeat`.
Then we set the correct values to one (the order is `(0, 1, 1, 0)` so we set every fourth value starting from the second value and every fourth value starting from the third value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

[The solution of @MaxNoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838030/5067311) is very instructive and meaningful (and I suggest using that solution, already due to its proper treatment of overlapping intervals). I just want to add that strictly speaking that solution doesn't give you rectangular pulses, but a series of broken lines which are very steep (but not vertical) at crossings.

So, for the sake of completeness, one way to generate your rectangular pulses (assuming that 1. your start and end times are stored in the arrays `starts` and `stops`, respectively, and 2. the intervals don't overlap!) is:

```
x,y=zip(*[(0,0)]+[item for start,stop in zip(starts,stops) for item in [(start,0),(start,1),(stop,1),(stop,0)]]+[(60,0)])
```

This will take every `start`-`stop` pair, duplicate them with a corresponding value of 1 or 0 in order to obtain rectangular pulses like `(start,0) -- (start,1) -- (stop,1) -- (stop,0)`, then adds starting and concluding data points, then assigns the constructed set of points to two arrays `x` and `y`. Plotting is done as usual, using `plt.plot(x,y)`.

**Edit:** here's a bit more verbose implementation of the same algorithm:

```
tmplist=[]
for start, stop in zip(starts, stops):
    tmplist.extend([(start,0),(start,1),(stop,1),(stop,0)])
tmplist=[(0,0)] + tmplist + [(60,0)]
x,y=zip(*tmplist)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Nice solution. But for me it definitely is far over the border where a one liner makes sense.  I would definitely split it up into a few lines in a proper for loop.

Comment: @MaxNoe thanks, I figured that your solution is more practical anyway, so I just left it in its original form, purely as a proof of concept. But yeah, you're right, I'll add an ungolfed version.

Comment: I added a numpy solution to my answer.

Comment: @MaxNoe yeah, I saw. It feels like it should be easily generalized to treat overlaps...but OP probably doesn't need that anyway.